# fontawesome cannot be used

Tags: html, font-awesome

I have quick question of using fontawesome icon in HTML.
I've tried the solutions to import the kit and link the all.css

```
 <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/"my kit id".js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
...
 <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
```

```
  <script src="css/all.css"></script>
...
 <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
```

but it still not worked.I don't understand how to solve this problem

Comment: If you press F12 in the browser, it will open the browser's developer tools. In there, you can view the network requests to check if all the resources were downloaded. You can also look in the console to see any other errors that the browser may have reported.

Comment: `src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/"my kit id".js"` does not seem like a valid path to me. DO you mean `src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/my_kit_id.js"`

Comment: @AndrewMorton sorry for the late reply, I have put my icon in div and opened the console to testify whether the icon was downloaded ,but I can only found my div area. Also there's no error showed up in console

Comment: @tacoshy exactly, my kit id is my own number kit id.it a numbered-key for my account to use the kit. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily to use `font-awesome` by using `CDN`:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
```

It should work!

Comment: It works! But I don't understand why it doesn't work when I imported my resources from my laptop. Is the version problem just a glitch?

Comment: It depends on your project structures, maybe you wrong path imported. You can `F12` to check what error is in the `console` tab. If my answer is helpful for you. Please mark it as `Accept answer`!